# Run a script on a gameobject once

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script which handles the translation of a gameobject over time using the `lerp` functionality of the Unity engine.

```
public class MovePiece : MonoBehaviour {
    Vector3 startPoint;
    Vector3 endPoint;
    float speed = 1;
    float startTime;
    float journeyLength;

    void Start() {
        startPoint = gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>().position;
        endPoint = startPoint + new Vector3(20, 0, 0); //Will make this a variable eventually
        startTime = Time.time;
        journeyLength = Vector3.Distance(startPoint, endPoint);
    }

    void Update() {
        float distCovered = (Time.time - startTime) * speed;
        float fracJourney = distCovered / journeyLength;
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPoint, endPoint, fracJourney);
    }
}
```

However, I only want this to run once when I click on a gameobject and then to detach itself from that object when it has finished moving it so that it can be run again next time I click on a different object.

I have a raycasting setup attached to the camera which allows me to select gameobjects, I just don't know how I'd then run this script on the selected object!

How can I do this?

Comment: @FarhanAnam, totally new to both c# and unity so have no idea what that is I'm afraid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rename your Start method

```
void Start() { ... }
```

to something that is publicly accessible by other components, ie:

```
public void BeginMove() { ... }
```

Then, have your Raycast script call your new function. You'll need to access the MovePiece component of the GameObject that was clicked:

```
...
GameObject hitObject = raycastHit.collider.gameObject;
MovePiece hitObjectMovePiece = hitObject.getComponent<MovePiece>();
hitObjectMovePiece.BeginMove();
```

You may also want to introduce a boolean lock to your animation. Here's what your code might look like.

```
    public class MovePiece : MonoBehaviour {
    Vector3 startPoint;
    Vector3 endPoint;
    float speed = 1;
    float startTime;
    float journeyLength;

    // Animation lock
    private bool moving = false;

    public void BeginMove() {
        startPoint = gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>().position;
        endPoint = startPoint + new Vector3(20, 0, 0); //Will make this a variable eventually
        startTime = Time.time;
        journeyLength = Vector3.Distance(startPoint, endPoint);

        moving = true;
    }

    void Update() {
        if(!moving)
            return;

        float distCovered = (Time.time - startTime) * speed;
        float fracJourney = distCovered / journeyLength;
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPoint, endPoint, fracJourney);

        if(fracJourney >= 1.0f)
            moving = false;
    }
}
```

I hope that helps! Best of luck.

Comment: This seems like it should work, however I'm getting an `object reference not set to an instance of an object` on the line where I call the `BeginMove()` function

Comment: @James Hm, is your object's Collider in a child transform? Make sure that your 'MovePiece' component is either on the same GameObject that has a Collider, or put the 'MovePiece' on the root GameObject, and change this line:

'GameObject hitObject = raycastHit.collider.gameObject;'

to this:

'GameObject hitObject = raycastHit.collider.transform.root.gameObject;'

Print out a quick 'Debug.Log(hitObject.name + " selected")' in your Raycast function so that you can easily tell which object is actually being selected.

Comment: Currently away from the computer ill so I cannot try this, I'm not being rude, I'll get back to you ASAP